# Passing data from python data frame into SQL table

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to create a new table in my SQL data base with the data from the data frame msft_data below. The msft_data, which is received by calling an API, looks like below. I've been trying for a while with chatgpt, google searches, etc. and keep running into errors. Would be very grateful if people can suggest a code that works to push data to my SQL server.

```
1. open      2. high 3. low    4. close    5. volume   date
2024-01-19   395.76  398.6700  393.5000    398.67  29331136.0
2024-01-18   391.72  393.9900  390.1200    393.87  23392068.0
2024-01-17   387.98  390.1100  384.8100    389.47  22234108.0
2024-01-16   393.66  394.0300  387.6229    390.27  27202268.0
2024-01-12   385.49  388.6800  384.6500    388.47  21661153.0
...             ...       ...       ...       ...         ...
2023-09-01   331.31  331.9900  326.7800    328.66  14942024.0
2023-08-31   329.20  330.9099  326.7800    327.76  26410954.0
2023-08-30   328.67  329.8100  326.4450    328.79  15222110.0
2023-08-29   321.88  328.9835  321.8800    328.41  19284590.0
2023-08-28   325.66  326.1500  321.7220    323.70  14808482.0
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy 

#API SCRIPT BELOW ----------------------------------------------------

# create Alpha Vantage API access
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
my_api_key = "#####"

# store last 100 days of stock prices
ts = TimeSeries(my_api_key, output_format='pandas')
msft_data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol="MSFT", outputsize="compact")
print(msft_data)

# open connection to SQL
 
connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-MLSEKPL\SQLEXPRESS;"
                      "Database=tracker;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

[SQL snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomGf.png)
[SQL credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKt8r.png)

- Tried bunch of scripts suggested by chatgpt and got a number of different errors
- Also tried google searches e.g., stack overflow existing scripts and didn't work for me
- Biggest issue is that i'm completely new to learning how to program so i'm sure there are obvious things that i missed

Comment: Please post errors of your attempt(s) so we can help diagnose the issue. Posted code does not attempt to save data to a database table.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

There is a pandas function to_sql that allows you to write a data frame to a SQL table.

Comment: I was trying that (as suggested by chatpgpt, etc.) but didn't have luck. Do you know the code that i need to write? Thank you!

Comment: Carefully read docs with examples (and not sinply run chatgpt answers). For this pandas method, except for SQLite DB, you must use an sqlalchemy engine for `con` argument which your posted code does not create. Simple DB-APIs like pyodbc will not work for this method.

Comment: Got it, will dig a bit deeper here. Thanks a lot :)